# Get rid of white background on embedded powerbi report

Tags: powerbi-embedded

My objective is to embed powerbi reports in a web application, without having a white wallpaper. When I open my repot in Power BI desktop I configutre the "Wallpaper" Color to transparency 100%. On actually embedding the report I use:

```
background: pbi.models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
```

But this does not help. When the report is embedded I still have a white background wall-paper thing, from the following classes:

```css
.reportContainerContent {
    background: #fff;
}
```

and

```css
.reportContainerContent .embeddedPV {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Where do I disable this - I simply want no wallpaper/background color.?

P.S removing the properties with the dev tools, get's the desired result

**update**

After a break from Power BI, I came back to working with embedding and found the issue + solution.
The trouble happened if the OS had dark theme enabled, and chrome was used. Read more [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1150352). The solution was simply to add `style="color-scheme: auto"` to the container div.

Answer (score 3):

In order to [apply a transparent background](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Transparent-Background) (Reference [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details#settings) - point #5), you must follow the following steps:

Step 1: Include the Power BI JS library in script (which you must have already done to embed the report):

```
<script src="https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/node_modules/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js"></script>
```

Step 2: Consume models from window:

```
var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
```

Step 3: Use the transparent background type from the consumed models and in the embed configuration add settings property as shown below:

```
var embedConfiguration = {
                            type: 'report',
                            tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
                            accessToken: token,
                            embedUrl: response.embedUrl,
                            id: reportId,
                            permissions: models.Permissions.ReadWrite,
                            viewMode: models.ViewMode.View,
                            settings: {
                                background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent
                            }
                        };
```

It worked for me.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

If you still face any issues, please provide your code snippet of the configurations.

Comment: Hi there - I'm actually just coming back to Power BI embedded. And I still have this issue  In your **After** example, what if your page-background was black? Because your example does not actually show if it's transparent or just white